# MATLAB method overriding behaviour: choose method from this class and not from the subclass

Tags: matlab, methods, subclass, superclass, overriding

Here are two example classes A and B. The class B is a subclass of A and overrides the method "myMethod":

```
classdef A

    methods
        function this = A()
            this.myMethod();
        end

        function myMethod(this)
            fprintf('A:myMethod\n');
        end
    end
end
```

---

```
classdef B < A

    methods
        function this = B()
            this@A();
            this.myMethod();
        end

        % Overrides 'myMethod' in A
        function myMethod(this)
            fprintf('B:myMethod\n');
        end
    end
end
```

---

Now, when I create an object of class B, the output is:

```
>> B();
B:myMethod
B:myMethod
```

**My question is:** How can I modify the constructor of class A such that the method from class A is called instead of the method from the subclass. The output should become:

```
>> B();
A:myMethod
B:myMethod
```

I have tried to do

```
this.myMethod@A();
```

in the constructor of A but it gives me an error saying that it only works for super class calls.

Thank you for the help,

Adrian

Comment: I think you used `A` in your question but meant `B`.

Comment: @Matt No! I really mean A!

Comment: I mean this sentence here: «How can I modify the class **A** such that in the constructor of **A**, the method from class **A** is called instead of the method from the subclass.» According to your expected output, you want to call the method of the superclass in the constructor of the subclass.

Comment: @Matt I edited the question to make it more clear. But I really wish to modify A and not B.

Comment: I see it now! If someone else wants to **reproduce** this, the line `this.myMethod();` in class B is not needed. When constructing B, then the method of class B is called in the constructor of A. The OP wishes there to call the method of class A and not of class B.

Comment: If the method called in `A`'s constructor never depends on `this`, you can declare it as `Static` and call the method from the class itself without an instance.  Would that suffice?

Comment: That's a good idea. It would solve the problem for this example, but in my actual code I need it to be a non-static method :(

Comment: I think only way is to add another method in A with different name and move contents of A:myMethod to that and then make A:myMethod and A:constructor call that method.

Comment: @Navan Yes, this is also my current solution to this problem. This is probably the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct but you cannot call superclass methods from the subclass **constructor**. If you use the same syntax in a different method in B() it will work fine. E.g., if we redefine class B() to look like this:

```
classdef B < A

    methods
        function this = B()
            this = this@A();
        end

        % Overrides 'myMethod' in A
        function myMethod(this)
            fprintf('B:myMethod\n');
            this.myMethod@A() ;
        end
    end
end
```

we get

```
>> B()
B:myMethod
A:myMethod

ans = 

  B with no properties.
```

The only superclass method you can call from a subclass constructor is the superclass constructor.

Comment: Hello, I see how your example works, but it is not quite what I need/described. I really want to modify the constructor of class A so that a call to "myMethod" is made but not the overridden "myMethod". I'm not sure if this is even possible...

Comment: Oh. Sorry. That error message you got about it only working for superclass calls I had only seen when trying to call a superclass method from a constructor. Guess I jumped ahead of myself. Should probably delete my answer?

Comment: Hey, that's no problem. Please don't delete your answer, I appreciate the effort you put into it. Thank you!